# How to loop content correctly

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop

I don't understand how the Python for loop works because I get a different result:

```
from itertools import groupby

 all = {}
 data = {'date': '10/12/19', 'name': 'jerry', 'id': 'Hello001'}

 for g , k in groupby(data, lambda r: (r[ 'date' ])):
        for i in k:
        #other data
        all.update({
            "date": i[ 'date' ],
            "name": i[ 'name' ],
        })

        print(all)
        for get in all:
            print(get)
```

Result of first print

```
{'date': '10/12/19', 'name': 'jerry', 'id': 'Hello001'}
```

Result of second print in loop

```
date
name
id
```

Why does the second print result only print the header?

Comment: Iteration over dictionary is just over its keys (the one you referred to as headers) and not values. If you want both keys and values, use `.items()`.

Comment: I did try `all.items()` in for loop but the data structure will not be the same as first print.

Comment: why should it be the same?

Comment: @Austin because I need the keep json format.

Comment: Isn't `all` already your required format?

Comment: @filipsoc You don't have JSON; you have a `dict`. If you need JSON, you'll want to reconstruct the `dict` anyway to pass to `json.dump` or `json.dumps`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print key and value you should do this

```py
for key in all:
    print(key, all[key])
```

Or you can use .items() method

```py
for key, value in all.items():
    print(key, value)
```